# How to address nested functions using Sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Using Sequelize in the code, I can't stub crucial inner functions of it, such as .save(), .scope(), etc.. Nesting doesn't seem to work.

As part of unit testing, the tests fail without proper handling of those functions, saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'returns' of undefined`

The error is being thrown during the execution of this line:

```
  subscription.save()
```

Implementation of the stub:

```
const deleteSubscription = async (subscriptionId) => {
  const ts = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  const subscription = await sql.Subscriptions.findByPk(subscriptionId);
  if (subscription == null) {
    throw new Error('Subscription not found', 'subscription_not_found')
  }
  subscription.deletedAt = ts
  subscription.save()
  return subscription
}
```

The unit-test:

```
    it('deleteSubscription succeeds', async () => {
        subscriptionsSqlStub.save.returns({})
        subscriptionsSqlStub.findByPk.returns({
            id: 1
        })
        const subscription = await subscriptions.deleteSubscription(subscriptionsSqlStub)
        expect(subscription).to.have.deep.property('id', 1)
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(subscriptionsSqlStub.findByPk)
        subscriptionsSqlStub.findByPk.resetHistory()
    })
```

How can I address the inner/nested functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried your code completely but I think it can be solved by adding `save()` in return response of `findByPk` so `subscription.save()` exists.

```
subscriptionsSqlStub.findByPk.returns({
  id: 1,
  save: () => true // adding save() here
});
```

Hope it works!